# Custom field FILE type location

Tags: wordpress, files

I have created a custom field of the FILE type.

When I attach a file, the file is stored on the server in this location:

`/my/server/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/custom`

Now this does have an .htaccess file to prevent access, but this is still technically a publicly accessible location.

Can the location of where these files are stored be changed/moved behind the public_html folder to say

`/my/server/cividocs/` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi @jsherk you can set the directories if you navigate to Administer>System Settings>Directories.

[image]